# Springs Transaction is silently rolled back

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a problem with a silent transaction rollback which causes an internal server error. I do have three classes (services):

```
class ServiceA {
    @Transactional
    public void methodA() {
        // ServiceB.methodB();
    }
}

class ServiceB {
    @Transactional
    public void methodB() {
        // ServiceC.methodC();
    }
}

class ServiceC {
    public void methodC() throws Exception {
        try {
            // ...
        } catch(EmptyResultDataAccessException e) {
            throw new Exception();
        }
    }
}
```

The `ServiceC` tries to remove an entity by the ID, so it calls `repository.deleteById(id)`. In case the resource was not found it does a catch on the `EmptyResultDataAccessException` exception and throws a checked exception with an information to the user.

I already tried to use `@Transactional(noRollbackFor = { Exception.class, RuntimeException.class })`, or even `EmptyResultDataAccessException.class` and the checked exception that is thrown, it's of type `CustomCheckedException.class`.

None of the solutions work, I need to not rollback the transaction if the data to delete is not found.

So, I have created a simple spring-boot example. It uses the H2 in-memory database. Below is the code that throws `EmptyResultDataAccessException` within a transaction, it should not rollback the transaction, but it does.

If we run the below code, we will get: `Caused by: org.springframework.transaction.UnexpectedRollbackException: Transaction silently rolled back because it has been marked as rollback-only`

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication implements CommandLineRunner {
    @Autowired
    private PetService petService;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(final String... args) throws Exception {
        petService.save(new Pet(), 1L);
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "pets")
class Pet {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    public Pet() {

    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(final Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}

@Repository
interface PetRepository extends JpaRepository<Pet, Long> {

}

interface PetService {
    void save(Pet pet, Long personId);
}

@Service
class DefaultPetService implements PetService {
    private final PetRepository repository;
    private final PersonService personService;

    DefaultPetService(
            final PetRepository repository,
            final PersonService personService
    ) {
        this.repository = repository;
        this.personService = personService;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(noRollbackFor = { EmptyResultDataAccessException.class })
    public void save(Pet pet, Long personId) {
        personService.deleteById(personId);
        repository.save(pet);
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "people")
class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    public Person() {

    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(final Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}

@Repository
interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, Long> {

}

interface PersonService {
    void deleteById(Long personId);
}

@Service
class DefaultPersonService implements PersonService {
    private final PersonRepository repository;

    DefaultPersonService(final PersonRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteById(Long personId) {
        try {
            repository.deleteById(personId);
        } catch(EmptyResultDataAccessException ignored) {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please make a [mcve] .  Otherwise all I can tell you is this should work, you must be doing something wrong. Which doesn't help at all of course.

Comment: @NathanHughes Below is the code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: If you will stop rethrowing the exception, then no rollback occurs

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with `RuntimeException`'s. If I will check first, if the entity exists in the database, and if it's not,  then throw a checked exception, then the transaction is not rolled back.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone still facing the issue can check by logging error in catch block of service, there might be few issues as

- Data is not compatible with column datatype
- Trying to persist null into not null
- Constraint may be violated.
- Id may not exist in DB(primary in case of deletion and FK in case of master- detail)

eg:

```
 @Override
@Transactional(noRollbackFor = { EmptyResultDataAccessException.class })
public void save(Pet pet, Long personId) {
    try{
     personService.deleteById(personId);
     repository.save(pet);
   catch(Exception exc){ 
        exc.printStackTrace();
      }
}
```